# Вложенные циклы и пример из книги

Tags: java

Не понимаю почему выдает определенную информацию в консоли вот этот код:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Это первый цикл! Я выполняюсь " + i + " раз");
        for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
            System.out.println("    Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь " + a + " раз");
            if (a == 2)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот что он выдает

```
   1. Это первый цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
           2.     Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
           3.    Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 2 раз
   4. Это первый цикл! Я выполняюсь 2 раз
           5.  Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
           6. Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 2 раз
   7.    Это первый цикл! Я выполняюсь 3 раз
           8.     Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
           9.    Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 2 раз
```

Вопрос почему на третьей строчке нам выдает:

Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 2 раз

Расписываю работу программы, как понял я:
Первый кусок кода у нас i меньше 3 (true) выполняется первый sout("Это первый цикл! Я выполняюсь " + i + " раз");

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Это первый цикл! Я выполняюсь " + i + " раз");
```

Всё окей

Дальше a меньше или ровно 10 (true) выполняется второй sout: Это второй цикл!
Я выполняюсь " + a + " раз");

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
                System.out.println("Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь " + a + " раз");

         Это первый цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
            Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
```

Потом как я понял идет if

```
if (a == 2)
break;
```

Где условие false и оператор break не выполняется, значит мы возвращаемся в цикл и по новой.
Вопрос почему я насчитал только такие выводы в консоль:

```
              Это первый цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
              Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
```

А программа выдает:

```
Это первый цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
           Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 1 раз
           Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь 2 раз (не понимаю, как он это в Sout вывел это)
и ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В цикле по a в первый раз `а=1` и это выводится.
Условие `if (a == 2)` не срабатывает - значит, цикл продолжается, a увеличивается.
В цикле по a на втором обороте `а=2` и это выводится.
Условие `if (a == 2)` **срабатывает**, цикл по a прекращается.

Получается, что код эквивалентен этому:

```
 for (int a = 1; a <= 2; a++){
        System.out.println("    Это второй цикл! Я выполняюсь " + a + " раз");
    }
```

Comment: спасибо понял!!